# How do I mix ip and name based virtualhosts on the same server?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, virtualhost, centos6

I currently have a production site on my server and i'm looking to add a development site. The production site is using the only ip address I have for a single domain SSL certificate. Is there a way I can add the development site without purchasing another ip. I don't necessarily need SSL for the development site. Perhaps a mix of ip and name based virtualhosts? The current setup is as follows:

```
# Production
NameVirtualHost 123.45.678.910:80

<VirtualHost 123.45.678.910:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 123.45.678.910:443

<VirtualHost 123.45.678.910:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks
Paul

EDIT

Would something like this work?

```
# Production
NameVirtualHost 123.45.678.910:80

<VirtualHost 123.45.678.910:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost 123.45.678.910:443

<VirtualHost 123.45.678.910:443>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/production
  ServerName www.example.com
</VirtualHost>

# Development

<VirtualHost 123.45.678.910:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/development
  ServerName dev.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Or would I need to use a different port, maybe 8080?

Comment: Did you mean `:443` on the last example?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat covered in the Apache documentation, but "basically" you can't do name based virtual hosts over SSL; the certificate exchange has to happen before the host header has been sent, and by that point it's too late.  You can do virtual SSL sites on alternate ports, though.

Otherwise, you can certainly do name-based virtual hosts on a non-SSL port.  Define your current production site first in the resultant config file to avoid problems.  It's just like using name-based virtual hosts on port 80 only, with one more virtual host on 443.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I updated my post. Would the above configuration work?

Comment: You can actually do named-based virtual hosts, either with a cert valid for multiple hosts, or by using SNI: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI

Comment: I was pretending that the SubjectAltName attribute doesn't exist, since that's technically sharing the same certificate across sites.  But SNI is legitimately new to me.  Hooray for learning stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You could either:

- Use a different port altogether.
- Use [name-based virtual hosts with a single certificate](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts). In this case, you would need to get a certificate with multiple Subject Alternative Names (`www.example.com` and `dev.example.com`), or perhaps wildcards (although that's a bit discouraged).
- Use [name-based virtual hosts with multiple certificates](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI), provided that your clients support SNI (which excludes any version of IE on XP, some mobile browsers and Java 6 and below).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I were to go with option 1 and use a different port number for the development site, would I be able to use an extended validation certificate for the production site? If so, how would the virtualhost configuration look? Also I need the production site to work for all browsers. Thanks again.

Comment: You should be able to. Option 1 is certainly the easiest, just make sure the `VirtualHost` sections are separated in the correct ports, and you might also need to enable `Listen xxxxx` on the right port.